# Have we ever seen a captured ship incorporated permanently in the enemy's fleet?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship

The threat of a starship being boarded and captured by enemy forces appears often in Star Trek franchise. On some occasions, such an operation is successful and the enemy gains the control over the starship. Such a starship is of great value for the enemy's intelligence services and would most likely be disassembled and studied by them. However, in situations when the ship's design is already known, or several ships of the same class are captured, there is no need to disassemble every one of them. Such ships can be manned by the enemy and be incorporated in the enemy's fleet.

There have been episodes in which a captured enemy ship is used for covert operations, however these ships do not last for long (like the Dominion's ship used by Starfleet).

Conditions I would like to exclude:

1. A captured ship used by an individual and not in actual control of enemy's fleet (like Dukat's Bird-of-Prey).
2. A captured ship used in one major operation and not used continuously by the enemy due to its destruction / becoming disabled / not being shown ever again (like Jem'Hadar fighter captured by Starfleet).

Have we ever seen a captured ship incorporated permanently in the enemy's fleet?

Comment: It strikes me that a captured ship would be a millstone. Constantly breaking down, hard to maintain, permanently lacking dedicated drydock facilities, in desperate need of hard-to-get spares and hated by the crews. Over time it would simply break as soon as a unique part was unavailable and you'd have to refit it to take your own systems, like O'Brien spent months/years trying to get DS9 to work properly.

Comment: You mean, like Deep Space 9? :)

Comment: I was also thinking of the Iraqi experience in Gulf I. They left entire batallions of tanks on the battlefield for the want of $1 parts that could have been easily sourced if they hadn't been under embargo.

Comment: And I was thinking about Earth "sea ships" being boarded and captured by enemy forces, repainted / given a new name and flag, and then used to attack the enemy and their former-sister ships. I AM aware that wooden ships were much simpler and more compatible than starships :) Still, I would like to see Starfleet facing a Galaxy-class starship repainted and manned by Klingons/Romulans, just because they failed to destroy it before it was captured.

Comment: The more complex a ship or vessel, the more requirement there is to have specialist single-usage parts. My car, for example, can't function without its computer module and those modules are only available from the manufacturer. In a few decades, those parts will be obsolete and the car will be too, even though it might remain in mint condition otherwise. And all for want of a $5 module.

Comment: And the question was inspired by this non-canon ship: http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/IKS_Qu%27

Comment: Seems to me that the best use of a captured enemy vessel would be to study its capabilities by putting it through its paces and then to disassemble it to determine its weaknesses and understand its advantages and/or new technology.

Comment: @DougR. - Sure, but what if you came into possession of multiple vessels?

Comment: @Valorum - Using the US Navy as an analogy, ships frequently return to the shipyards to have systems upgraded, and they may not update a generation 3 system to generation 4, but they might update a generation 2 to generation 6 (it's not cost-effective). I.e., if the )*&#*&% happened to capture both NCC-17905 & NCC-17906, they may have different generations of different systems, based on when they were last in for refit. I.e, 905 may have a newer warp drive and weapons technology, but 906 may have newer shields. Also, two ships of the same class built 3 years apart may have different systems.

Comment: @DougR. - When the Allies came into the possession of Axis vessels during the war, they repurposed some but mostly just melted the others down for scrap

Comment: This _sounds_ like something the Borg should be doing, but I'm not sure if there's any evidence of it, and furthermore I'm not sure if disassembling a ship down to its nuts and bolts and rebuilding it as a platonic solid is really within the spirit of the question.

Comment: @Valorum - I'm aware of that. However at the time we were at war and the technological playing field was fairly level. A more comparable circumstance would have been when the Soviets a ballistic missile sub in either the '70s or '80s, they scuttled it to ensure that the US couldn't recover it to study the technology, which would have given us a much better picture of enemy capabilities.

Comment: @Valorum yes, the Allies left whole ships at dock, for want of 5 deutshe-mark parts that could have been easily sourced if they hadn't been under embargo.

Comment: @Harper - They mostly scuttled 'em, used 'em for target practice or smelted them down to make cutlery.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The [Kazon fleet](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Predator_class) comprises entirely of vessels taken from their former enslavers, the [Trabe](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Trabe)

> **NEELIX**: *They're Trabe vessels, actually. Everything the Kazon have, they stole from the Trabe. Mabus will tell you all about it over
>   a sumptuous dinner. The food hasn't been very good where we've been.*

[image]

Comment: Interesting find! Although I find it hardly surprising that revolutionaries permanently incorporate the military equipment left behind by the recently overthrown government. ;-) Which makes sense because the new government has access to the same supporting resources (both experience/documentation and maintenance tools) – especially considering your highly praised comment underneath the question.

Answer (score 28):

While Terok Nor isn't technically a *ship*, it is capable of moving around inside the Bajor system under its own steam. It's renamed Deep Space Nine and is used extensively by the Federation and Bajorans.

Comment: Well, it isn't a ship, as you mentioned, but I haven't thought of that at all. Nice one!

Comment: If nothing else, it shows that the Federation aren't averse to using non-standard stations (and possibly ships) when the need arises. Much the same is true in TNG: Encounter at Farpoint where they plan to use a pre-built ground station.

Comment: I have to downvote because DS9, as you pointed, isn't a ship, but also it's legally a Bajoran station not a StarFleet one, it moved only once through the show and nearly tore itself apart in the process, and I'm not convinced about the bunch of Bajoran's sublight raiders/fighters being called a 'fleet'. And, as far as I know, the Bajorans didn't board and capture Terok Nor, more like the Cardassians abandoned it when the retreated from the Bajoran system and the Bajorans moved in afterwards.

Comment: @Sava - It is, however, incorporated into the Bajoran fleet. It was also (on at least one occasion) captured and used by the Dominion, then re-captured by the Federation.

Comment: @Valorum Can we really say that the Bajorans have a fleet? Given what we've seen, it feels like a single runabout would be able to quickly dispatch all of the Bajoran's military spacecraft and receive little damage in the process. True on the capture part, though it can be said that the Dominion just took back something that belonged to one of their members.

Comment: @Sava - They have sufficient ships to form a (relatively in)effective blockade; http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Bajoran_interceptor

Comment: I concur.   This answer doesn't satisfy either the letter or the intent of the question.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Who are you concurring with? Or are you just [generally concurring](https://gfycat.com/gifs/detail/sorrowfulidealisticgarpike)?

Comment: @Valorum:   I guess I'm concurring with Sava over the downvote.   It's not a ship and it's not integrated into a fleet.   And even if it is, there's a difference between integrating a ship and taking over a base.   If this is anything, it's an answer to a different question.

Answer (score 24):

U.S.S. Defiant, [NCC-1764](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Trek_Starfleet_starships#Constitution_class), Constitution class cruiser.

Originally built by:

> United Federation of Planets

Captured by:

> The Tholian Assembly in TOS [S3E09](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tholian_Web) "The Tholian Web"

Captured by, and incorporated into the fleet of:

> The Terran Empire (Mirror Universe) in [ENT S4E18 & S4E19](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_a_Mirror,_Darkly) "In a Mirror, Darkly"

Answer (score 2):

There is another example of this that seems to have been missed.

Gul Dukat captures a Klingon Bird-of-Prey (DS9:[Return to Grace](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Return_to_Grace_(episode)) and incorporates it into the joint cardassian/dominion fleet. (DS9: [In Purgatory's Shadow](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/In_Purgatory%27s_Shadow_(episode)) & [By Inferno's Light](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/By_Inferno%27s_Light_(episode))

Answer (score 1):

Although it didn't last too long, the Nyrians captured Voyager in [Displaced](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Displaced).  After all the Voyager crew were replaced, their leader stated "Your vessel will be used to defend Nyrian acquisitions."

Comment: The question ask for ship that are 'permanently' added to the fleet, not temporarily.

Comment: @Sava - Sure, but the aim seems to have been to include it in their fleet

Comment: @Sava True, I did overlook that.